# Reopen review queue acting up?

Tags: support, review, re-open

The [Reopen review queue](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen) is acting really strange today.

All of a sudden, it contains loads of questions for review (180 reviews today on 3600 ever). Moreover, the queue contains questions that were "edited since they were closed". But the "revision" tab states:

[image: No changes to display]

Given that there are questions which were last edited over a year ago, I presume there was some query run by the system to bring back these old questions for review.

Nonetheless it is strange that there are questions brought up in the queue even without changes to display.

Can we get some more information on this?

Comment: There are some details about the change [in this post on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/151385)

Comment: Thanks. Incidentally, I had just found the exact same post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Reopen review queue has been modified as follows ([MSO source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/222340)):

> Currently, this means that a closed question will automatically be added to the reopen queue when it is...
>
> - ...Edited (body edits only) within 5 days of closure by the author. Or,
> - ...Edited (body edits only) within 5 days of closure by a 3rd-party, provided the editor has not also flagged the question or voted to delete it. Or,
> - ...Sufficiently popular, where popularity is calculated based on question score, top answer score, or views per month. We're still tweaking the exact thresholds for these, but right now they're fairly generous - however, the most popular closed questions are being added to the queue *first*.